# ifstream giving me trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, ifstream

im using fstream to get visual studio to read a file with about 100 lines of repeated info, just different values every line. Im using a count variable to keep track of how many times this is read, but it keeps saying 0. i know the file is being opened because i placed an If statement to check for me. and yes the file im reading from is also the location of my cpp file. If you could take a look and tell me what im missing i would appreciate it!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
//file variables
string date;
int rainIn, minTempF, maxTempF;

//variables
int count = 0;
double totalRain = 0;
double averageMinimumTemp = 0;
double averageMaximumTemp = 0;
double overallMaxTemp = 0;
double overallMinTemp = 0;

ifstream inFile("2014WeatherData.txt");

if (!inFile) {
    cout << "Error: Input File Cannot Be Opened\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//read file records
while (inFile >> date >> rainIn >> maxTempF >> minTempF) {
    count++
}

cout << count << " Records read\n";

return 0;
}
```

im only in computer science 1, so im still learning any feedback will be very much appreciated!!
also here is a few lines from the txt document im trying to read from

```
20140101    0.00    69.08   31.10
20140102    0.00    42.98   25.16
20140103    0.00    51.98   25.16
```

Comment: Why don't you put the `cout << count...` line inside the loop to make sure any records are being successfully read? My guess is the reading is failing.

Comment: It may help to post the first few lines of the file you are reading (cut'n'paste what is *actually* in the file - no cheating)

Comment: well i have the if statement there to check to see if the file is opening. im not receiving the error message. when i take the txt document out of the containing folder i do receive the message though. But when i put the txt document back i dont receive the message

Comment: also added the first three lines of the txt document. all the other lines are just like this one

Comment: Just because the file opened, doesn't mean you are reading the data correctly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that...

```
int rainIn, minTempF, maxTempF;
```

...creates `int`eger variables, and you try to read floating point values into them.  Change them to `double`s.  (You also need a semicolon after `count++`).